# How do I solve the index error generated in matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am learning the animation tool in matplotlib, but I am running into error in the following code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,4,6,4])
y = np.array([2,5,4,7,9])

x_points, y_points = [],[]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [],[]
line, = plt.plot([],[],'ro')

def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    return line, 

def animate(i):
   x_points.append(x[i])
   y_points.append(y[i])
   line.set_data(x_points,y_points)
      return line 

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,
   frames = 200,interval=500,blit=False)

plt.show()
```

I am getting the below error. How do I solve it?

```
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You have too many frames *(`200`)* for the lists `x` and `y`. Since `x` and `y` both have the length of `5`, the maximum value you can set the `frames` argument to is `5`:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=5, interval=500, blit=False)
```

To elaborate, each frame uses up one index of the `x` and `y` lists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have a new error. My code doesn't plot data.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar Maybe that could be a separate question?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar Please don't change your question on the same post, as user's answers will be invalidated that way. Instead, post a separate one.